# Trigger iOS 13 dialog during development: "continue to always allow background location use"

Tags: swift, core-location, ios13

Our app uses [`CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization) to set up geofence monitoring on a fixed location. On iOS 13, this causes three system dialogs to pop up in succession, with a timing twist. I'll list all three here for context and searchability, but this S.O. question is specifically about the last one:

1. **"Allow 'App-Name' to access your location?"** shows up immediately, with the three buttons:

   - **Allow While Using App**
   - Allow Once
   - Don't Allow
2. **"Allow 'App' to also access your location even when you are not using the app?"** shows up a little later, when iOS determines you're not actively using it. This can vary from seconds to minutes after going to the home screen or locking your device. It has two options:

   - **Keep Only While Using**
   - Change to Always Allow
3. **"'App' has used your location X times in the background over the past 3 days. Do you want to continue to allow background location use?"** shows up after three consecutive days with at least one background location update, together with these buttons:

   - Change to Only While Using
   - Always Allow

The third and last dialog box also contains a map, showing which locations the app was triggered at. It so happens that that map is the part of the app that we're trying to test – to make sure our app is only ever informed at the right location, and that it contains the right copy writing and amount of text.

The thing is, I can't figure out how to trigger this dialog box "early" during development, without having to wait three days!  So here's the question for now:

### Who knows how to somehow trigger the dialog (with the mini-map) for development purposes?

[image: Screenshot borrowed from Quartz]

Cheers,
Eric-Paul

Comment: Very good idea but it can’t be done so basically this is just a complaint. Anyway location stuff has always been hard to test.  File a feature request with Apple perhaps.

Comment: If it can't be done, "it can't be done" would be a perfectly fine answer to the question. I couldn't find any resources on this. Do you have any source material to point to?

Comment: No, just experience and what Apple says in the WWDC 2019 video on this topic. But there is clearly no "back door" way of triggering these authorization dialogs. If the system's rule is that you get a dialog after 3 days, you get a dialog after three days. :)

Comment: Of course I could ask you _why_ you think you need to trigger this dialog. If you are handling authorization coherently there should not be any need to "test" this.

Comment: Of course, but if you happen to work on an app with several hundred thousand active users in an organisation with thousands of employees, you can reduce a lot of incoming e-mails by testing before shipping. Regardless, that's not what this question is about, thanks.